# Sort map on value?

Tags: java

if i have a map like this:

```
Map<Fruit, Double> multiMap = new HashMap<Fruit, Double>();
```

is there a way for me to sort on the Double values while still keeping the Double values linked to the corresponding Fruit object?

initially i was thinking of doing something like this:

```
public ArrayList<Double> sortAllValues() {
    ArrayList<Double> allEntries = new ArrayList<Double>();

    for (Entry<Fruit, Double> entry : multiMap.entrySet())
        allEntries.add(entry.getValue());
    }
return Collections.sort(allEntries);
}
```

but if i do this i lose the linkage between the Fruit and the Double value... any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hashtables do not store any order and are not intended for keeping inorder data

Comment: Perhaps you want an array of fruit, and sort them by the double that they map to.

Comment: Looks like it's exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: It looks like you just want to sort the values as oppose to the keys. This has been answered before like @baraky pointed out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a Map? Why not bring the double into your Fruit class so it is always together?

Comment: what does this have to do with multimaps?

Comment: Can you give a before-and-after example of what your multimap would look like before and after sorting?  It's not at all clear what kind of sorting you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider the following:

```
class ValuedFruit implements Comparable<ValuedFruit> {
    private Fruit fruit;
    private double value;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ValuedFruit o) {
        return (value < o.value) ? -1 : ((value > o.value) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
List<ValuedFruit> fruits = new ArrayList<ValuedFruit>();
void sort(List<ValuedFruit> fruits){
    Collections.sort(fruits);
}
```

Comment: The compareTo method could just contain `return Double.compare(this.value, o.value)`, which would have the bonus of not breaking the ordering if any value happens to be NaN.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible that you can maintain order of map entries(key,value) based on the value but it could possible based on key with `TreeMap<k,v>`.

> TreeMap is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by
>   a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used. This implementation provides guaranteed log(n)
>   time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations.

What you could possibly do that is update your code -

```
public ArrayList<Double> sortAllValues() {    
     return Collections.sort(multiMap.values());
}
```

It will stop unnecessary iteration.

Comment: for some reason, your answer looks very odd + this sentence made no sense whatsoever to me. **There is no way where you can sort map entry(key,value) on based on value but based on value it is possible with TreeMap<k,v>**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: Thanks for commenting I have updated it

Answer (score 1):

You just have single double value associated with every Fruit object. If this is the case then sorting doesn't make any sense. If you have multiple double values associated with a single Fruit object then change the structure of your map to something like this :

```
Map<Fruit, Set<Double>> multiMap = new HashMap<Fruit, Set<Double>>();
```

You can use TreeSet, to keep the values sorted.